# Running the same node on multiple image messages parallel

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, parallel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ros comunity.

I have six cameras, where i would like to do object classification, with YOLOv3 using [darknet_ros](https://github.com/leggedrobotics/darknet_ros), on each of the camera inputs, at the same time. I am using a Jetson AGX Xavier, with ros-melodic, cuda and opencv installed, and i can acces the cameras through ethernet.

My question is:
What would be the smartest and ideal way to handle multiple image messages (or messages in general) in parallel, using the same node?

It would be nice if someone could point me in the direction of the theory that i need to solve my problem most efficiently.

Have a nice day.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348277/running-the-same-node-on-multiple-image-messages-parallel./) by [bachla](https://answers.ros.org/users/53167/bachla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a quick comment: if "the node" hasn't been written with this in mind, then the answer would be: you can't.

Of course, I'm assuming here that "the same node" means: "with a single running process". If instead you meant: with multiple running instances of the same node *type*, then you should be able to start as many as you need in separate namespaces and have each of them subscribe to the appropriate topics.

Depending on how many resources the node uses / requires (especially: GPU resources here as you mention CUDA), you should be able to start multiple. But that really depends on how "the node" has been written.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bachla](https://answers.ros.org/users/53167/bachla/) on 2020-04-14**:
Thank you for the response.
I meant running multiple instances of the same node type but on different inputs, and as you said, using different namespaces, was the way to go.